# Resgatar texto HTML do banco de dados MySQL com o EJS (Node.js)

Tags: mysql, node.js, tinymce, ejs

Estou desenvolvendo um portal de notícias em Node.js onde salvo os posts em um banco de dados MySQL. Como template engine, uso o EJS.

Uso o plugin Tinymce para formatar o texto dos posts (usar negrito, italico e etc). O Tinymce é um editor visual para páginas da Internet robusto escrito completamente em JavaScript.

Este plugin salva no banco de dados o texto já formatado em HTML. Por exemplo:

```
<strong>negrito</strong> e <p>texto em paragrafo</p>
```

O problema está na hora de apresentar este conteúdo. Faço a consulta no banco de dados e retorna com as tags, e não o texto formatado. Estou chamando o tinymce da maneira correta:

```
<script src="tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
```

E está salvando certo no banco. Mas quando realizo a consulta para visualizar, ele mostra assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código da view é este:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="noticia_wrapper">
                    <span class="noticia_autor"><%= noticia[0].autor %></span>
                    <span class="noticia_titulo"><%= noticia[0].titulo %></span>
                    <span class="noticia_data"><%= moment(noticia[0].data_criacao).format('DD/MM/YYYY') %></span>
                    <br />
                    <p class="noticia_resumo">
                        <%= noticia[0].noticia %>
                    </p>                        
                </div>
            </div>
```

Alguém pode dar uma luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precisas que o EJS mostre esse HTML sem o escapar. [Olhando para a documentação](https://github.com/tj/ejs#features) o comando para isso é `<%-`, assim podes fazer:

```
<p class="noticia_resumo">
    <%- noticia[0].noticia %>
</p>
```

Comment: Meu amigo Sergio, muito obrigado. Tenho quebrado a cabeça com isso já há algum tempo... Confesso que não conhecia o lance de escapar e não escapar o HTML, então, quando olhei a documentação, não achei a solução. Muito, mas muito obrigado mesmo cara.

Comment: @RodrigoZandonadi otimo poder ajudar. Se quiseres podes clicar e marcar a resposta como aceite.

Comment: Sergio, eu tentei, mas como sou usuário novo meu voto não é computado... sorry

Comment: @RodrigoZandonadi para aceitar não precisas de pontos. É um simbolo por baixo das setas de votar e da pontuação da resposta.

Comment: @RodrigoZandonadi https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/129